# React use-screen-shot unable to take a screenshot of an Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using use-screen-shot to take screenshot in React. Everything is working fine but the only thing missing is the image. Now if image's source is local, I can take screenshot of it. But if it's url, it shows a white space.

I can't seem to make it work. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

To load image data into JavaScript (which is required by useScreenShot) you need to have permission to do so.

For local images, that is automatic. For crossorigin images you need to:

- Add the [`crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin) to request permission via CORS (e.g. `<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" crossOrigin="anonymous" />`)
- Have the server use CORS response headers to grant you permission to read it

You can't load image data across origins without [permission from the source of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068). The usual alternatives to CORS (as per the answer in the previous link), such as using a proxy, apply.

Comment: crossOrigin="anonymous" making me unable to load the image because of CORS policy. Should this be handled in server side?

Comment: @İlker — You need to do **both** things I mentioned in bullet points. The HTML needs the crossorigin attribute. The server needs to grant permission. It is not one-or-the-other. You need both.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/w0kpjh?file=/src/components/Image.js can you try this one? it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the image into base64 format and it'll work bro.
instead of setting src="https://" you can just use the base64 format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).